# can't load PHP extension

Tags: php, windows, apache

I'm using Apache2.4 with php7 on Windows 2008 server.

Some extensions are enabled in php.ini 
[image]

If you run php -m you can see they are installed

[image]

But when I put this code into a .php file under apache/htdocs and access it via localhost/aaa.php

```
<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

Those enabled extensions are not shown, the output is

```
Array ( [0] => Core 
        [1] => bcmath 
        [2] => calendar 
        [3] => ctype 
        [4] => date 
        [5] => filter 
        [6] => hash 
        [7] => iconv 
        [8] => json 
        [9] => SPL 
        [10] => pcre 
        [11] => readline 
        [12] => Reflection 
        [13] => session 
        [14] => standard 
        [15] => mysqlnd 
        [16] => tokenizer 
        [17] => zip 
        [18] => zlib 
        [19] => libxml 
        [20] => dom 
        [21] => PDO 
        [22] => Phar 
        [23] => SimpleXML 
        [24] => xml 
        [25] => wddx 
        [26] => xmlreader 
        [27] => xmlwriter 
        [28] => apache2handler 
    )
```

If I put this into a.php and access it via localhost, I can also see GD is not installed.

```
<?php if ( extension_loaded( 'gd' ) ): ?>
                    <li class="success">GD extension loaded.</li>
<?php else: $success = FALSE; ?>
                    <li class="fail">You do not have the GD PHP extension loaded.</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, if I run php.exe a.php, the result says GD is loaded.

So seems runing via the apache server and local php executable return different results. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: can you check with `php -i | grep php.ini` and `phpinfo();` whether both instances are using the same php.ini?

Comment: Have you restarted the Apache server after making the changes to php.ini?

Comment: Apache normally uses a different `php.ini` file to the CLI. Did you amend BOTH `php.ini` files? You will probably find the one used by Apache in the `apache\bin` folder

Comment: if I run php.exe -S localhost:8080 on apache/htdocs to launch a built-in server, get_loaded_extensions() can show those extensions!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have yet to encounter that situation in Windows when Apache and PHP are installed independently. Is that a WAMP-specific wonky-ness?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well I am a WAMP user. So _wonkey-ness_ comes naturally

Comment: @MonkeyZeus xampp works fine, but xampp is for development purpose I think so need to install Apache and php separately I guess.

Comment: php -i gives
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\php\php.ini and there's no php.ini in Apache/bin

Comment: @RiggsFolly You have my sympathies. Once you learn how to install them independently then you learn to vehemently avoid WAMP and it's other incarnations. However, if you are on Mac then MAMP is your best bet for being productive.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sympathy is not necessary. It works for me and I have never had issues moving my code to unix/linux boxes before that misnoma occurs to you

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` from both the command line and your browser and you will quickly find out where your `ini`s are coming from.

Comment: Hi guys, I found a php_errors.txt in Apache24, shows 'mysqli' (tried: ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0, let me check it out!

Comment: Do you have the right path for `extension_dir` in your php.ini? Also, are you editing the right php.ini file used by apache? Usually cli, and apache uses two different ini files. To find the php.ini file used by apache, create a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and load it in your browser, then look for the `Configuration File` directive there.

Comment: Guys, issue fixed. Browser and CLI use same php/php.ini but my config for extension folder is wrong, changing it from extension_dir = "ext" (which is default) to extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" fixed the issue!

Comment: Add the extension to ```/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini``` instead of ```/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini```. It works perfectly